VBA class member function and class definition problem continues Vol 3
The story continues ... my earlier two questions were about the member functions fReadData and fReadData2
Public Function fReadData(alue As Range) As Double

    pOne = alue.Cells(1)
    fReadData = pOne
    
End Function

Public Function fReadData2(alue As Range) As ClassOne

    Set fReadData2 = New ClassOne
    
    pOne = alue.Cells(1)
    fReadData2.One = pOne
        
End Function

Now both version works (listing are OK), but now I am wondering why the fReadData3 below gives always the same result as fReadData or fReadData2 ?  The only difference compared to fReadData2 is the additional variable foo.
Public Function fReadData3(alue As Range) As ClassOne
    
    Set fReadData3 = New ClassOne
    Dim foo As Double
    
    foo = alue.Cells(1)
    fReadData3.One = foo
    
    
End Function

Some tests:

The function Test has been run just before Test3.

Test3 gives the same value as Test

When Test2 is run prior Test3, Test3 gives the same as Test2

The class ClassOne is as follows
'ClassOne

Option Explicit

Private pOne As Double


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    
End Sub


Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    
End Sub


Public Property Get One() As Double
    One = pOne
End Property


Public Property Let One(lOne As Double)
    pOne = lOne
End Property


Public Function fReadData(alue As Range) As Double

    pOne = alue.Cells(1)
    fReadData = pOne
    
End Function


Public Function fReadData2(alue As Range) As ClassOne

    Set fReadData2 = New ClassOne
    
    pOne = alue.Cells(1)
    fReadData2.One = pOne
    
    
End Function

Public Function fReadData3(alue As Range) As ClassOne
    
    Set fReadData3 = New ClassOne
    Dim foo As Double
    
    foo = alue.Cells(1)
    fReadData3.One = foo
    
    
End Function

The testing from worksheet is as follows
' main module

Option Explicit


Dim oOne As New ClassOne



Function Test(alue As Range) As Double

oOne.fReadData alue

Test = oOne.One

End Function



Function Test2(alue As Range) As Double

oOne.fReadData2 alue

Test2 = oOne.One

End Function

Function Test3(alue As Range) As Double

oOne.fReadData3 alue

Test3 = oOne.One

End Function


I'm not following. Why would you expect fReadData3 to not to give the same result as fReadData2? It seems to me they are simply equivalent and the additional variable foo doesn't change anything meaningfully as far as the result is concerned.

Above Test and Test3 reads different cells ( and different values ) from worksheet, that means fReadData2 and fReadData3 have different input values.

Your functions fReadData2 and fReadData3 return a class object which is strange for a function in VBA (a function that would go in a worksheet cell, anyway). Not really seeing what you are trying to do. Its frankly unnecessary to create custom classes in vba just to read a value from a cell. You don't even need VBA at all to do that. I'm not trying to be difficult, but when I see overly complicated code to do something simple, my answer is usually to get rid of the complicated code.

Oh.
Public Function fReadData3(alue As Range) As ClassOne
  Set fReadData3 = New ClassOne
  Dim foo As Double
  foo = alue.Cells(1)
  fReadData3.One = foo
End Function

Function Test3(alue As Range) As Double
  oOne.fReadData3 alue
  Test3 = oOne.One
End Function

fReadData3 creates the new object and assign the value you need to this object, but in Test3 you want to get this value from another object.
The right code:
Function Test3(alue As Range) As Double
  dim tmp
  set tmp = oOne.fReadData3(alue)
  Test3 = tmp.One
End Function

Or, if you don't need the returned object any more:
Function Test3(alue As Range) As Double
  Test3 = oOne.fReadData3(alue).One
End Function

Typically, a new object is created by the existing object to provide a copy of the last one or if the new object is somehow based on the existing object.
Due to some restrictions in VBA (absence of the public constructor, the public constructor with parameters), you can create the new object by class's method like the constructor.
